# Discrepancy while inserting data in MongoDB through pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a JSON file with 20 records.
I tried inserting data from the JSON into MongoDB through python(pymongo to be specific).
Following is the python code.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint
import json

# creating a mongo db client and connecting with
# the fantasyscout database.
# Inserting the players in the collection(table)
# players.
client = MongoClient()
db = client.fantasyscout

# Reading the data from the dumper json file
with open("C:\\team.level.json") as db_data:
data = json.load(db_data)

# Reading every element in the JSON data and
# inserting in the db.
print len(data)
print data[str(20)]
for element in range(1,++len(data)):
    db.team_level.insert(data[str(element)])
```

The len(data) holds the value 20 (confirmed by printing in python). Though after running this script, the no. of records inserted are 19 and the `data["20"]` is not inserted.
After changing the range manually to (1,21), the script enters all 20 records.
I am missing something very trivial . Please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For loop from 0 to 2, therefore running 3 times.

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    print "We're on time %d" % (x)
```

that means you need to iterate from `0` not from `1`

[reference](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)